# Pair javascript objects and assign same color

Tags: javascript

Is it possible to find a better/ modular way to assign the same color to paired rather than hard-coding them as I currently implement?

If objects `fname` matches, then assign the same color.

The following is a subset of javascript objects.

```
data[0] = [{
    "value": 29,
    "series": 1,
    "category": "Men",
    "fname": "NY",
     "valueColor": "red"
},


data[1] = [{
    "value": 19,
    "series": 4,
    "category": "Women",
    "fname": "NY",
     "valueColor": "red"
},

data[2] = [{
    "value": 9,
    "series": 3,
    "category": "LG",
    "fname": "NY",
    "valueColor": "red"
},
```

Here is the full implementation in **[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/fm79hsms/5/)**

First I assume, all objects are different and assign a different color, then I will check if there are any paired objects, if yes, then assign the same color.

Therefore it would be nice to generate `colorSpectrum` based on a number of objects in exists in datasets rather than assigning common colors such as red, green, yellow, etc.. because you cannot guess in advance how many different objects you would get. I might get around maybe 10 objects, maybe around 100 objects. Therefore, I am looking for a modular way to handle this difficulty.

Here is the `colorSpectrum` method implementation in **[COLOR SPECTRUM FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/qajz9h29/1/)**

Comment: You want all objects sharing a common *fname* value to have the same *valueColor* value as well? If so, how do you determine the appropriate color for a given *fname* value?

Comment: Yes, Jonathan exactly. Please see my updated question.

Comment: Does your site use lodash by chance?

Comment: First time I heard `lodash`, it means no.

Comment: @AndreaBanderas What do you mean when you suggesting generating a color based on the number of objects that exist? Should objects with more instances have a *darker* color, for instance?

Comment: Also, are you counting the number of objects across `data[0]`, `data[1]`, etc? Or are you only counting similar objects in the same top-level array index?

Comment: Hello Jonathan, I have given code as well. Actually, I wont know how many objects will exist in total. Therefore, based on the number of objects, I generate colorspectrum, then check if `fname` is same, then assign the same color across.

Comment: Yes, I should count the number of objects in `data[0]`, `data[1]`, `data[2]`,. etc. First I assume, all objects are different and assign a different color, then I will check if there are any paired objects, if yes, then assign same color.

Comment: @JonathanSampson, is my question clear as it stands now?

Comment: So the common color should be the total number of objects with a shared *fname* property, used as an index in the color spectrum? So, if we have 25 "NY" objects, they should have whatever color is at `colorSpectrum[24]`?

Comment: Lets assume `data[0].length+data[1].length+data[2].length` is 20. Than it means I should have 20 different colors and assigned each object initially. Then I will check if there is any common `fname`'s name in the `dataset [data[0],data[1], data[2]]`, if yes, then make/assign the same color for these objects.please let me know , if that is clear?

Comment: Assigning same color to objects with same `fname` is clear. To me, understanding the spectrum was difficult. Anyways, are you looking for something like this http://jsfiddle.net/dhirajbodicherla/fm79hsms/7/ ? In this example, 18 spectrum colors are generated as per the data and objects with same fname have same color.

Comment: Yes, exactly. please provide as an answer, then I will upvote and mark it. The only thing that bothers me, legends colors is not updated afterwards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like this.

```
function colorSpectrum(N) {
    var colorMap = [], inc = 50, start = 1000;
    for (i = start; i < start+N*inc; i+=inc) {
        var num = ((4095 * i) >>> 0).toString(16);
        while (num.length < 3) {
            num = "0" + num;
        }
        colorMap.push("#" + num);
    }
    return colorMap;
}

function process(data){
    var map = {}, colorMap = colorSpectrum(data.length);
    data.forEach(function(item, index){
        if(!map.hasOwnProperty(item.fname)){
            map[item.fname] = colorMap[index];
        }
        data[index].valueColor = map[item.fname];
    }); 

    return data;
}

data = process(data);
```

Here is a demo **http://jsfiddle.net/dhirajbodicherla/fm79hsms/7/**

Comment: Do you have any idea why legends do not match with bar stack chart colors?

Comment: @AndreaBanderas: That is so weird. No matter which color the chart is, the legend color doesn't seem to change. I will let you know once I figure out something.

Comment: I have got an answer, but when I combine it, it does not work. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30656016/legend-and-bar-chart-colors-do-not-match

Comment: @AndreaBanderas: looks super hacky. But only the last 3 legend items are working. Insane !

Comment: I think we are doing something fundamentally wrong in grouping. If I give this `group: { field: "fname" }` the legend seems to be working. I cannot totally conclude, but having same colors based on `fname` might be the problem because the chart itself gives a color based on groups

Comment: could u please share fiddle?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/dhirajbodicherla/9t1gnfrk/6/ in this sample, colors are set based on `series` instead of `fname` and legend colors work perfectly

Comment: But now you lost paired object same color. Just watch `NY` object color across the bar stack.

Comment: True. That is exactly my point. Kendo generates charts by grouping `series` and the legend color is based on that grouping. By explicitly setting legends colors based on `fname`, the original legend coloring is violated.

Comment: Check the following jsfiddle that I made it work http://jsfiddle.net/1ost124j/1/ I have added `e.series.data[i].fname != ""` into `if (e.series.data[i].valueColor != "" && e.series.data[i].fname != "")`

Comment: @AndreaBanderas: NICE !! How ?

Comment: Because your solution looks for dataset length, even there is no `fname`, but still generates color for that objects as well, therefore I need to add that criteria to make it work properly. When I debug , then I have realized there is a bug.

Comment: Now, I need to figure out, how to assign `fname` as a legend! Do you have any thing in your mind?  I need to tweak the following  `var label = new kendo.drawing.Text(e.series.name, [0, 0]`.. Thanks a lot Dhiraj for helping me out. Appreciated!

Comment: Here is my question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30658508/custom-legend-label