# Custom Legend Label

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, kendo-chart

I have the following implementation, it works and functional. However I would like to assign `fname` attribute as a legend, not `series` attribute.

I believe that I need to work on the following line of code, but I could not able to figure out yet.

```
var label = new kendo.drawing.Text(e.series.name, [0, 0], {
  fill: {
     color: "black"
  }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/1ost124j/1/

Comment: something like `e.series.data[1].fname` ? Not totally sure though. Works for first 3 only http://jsfiddle.net/dhirajbodicherla/1ost124j/2/ ! Again :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like `e.series.data[1].fname` should do it.

---

More accurately (based on your suggestion) the below is the fully working code

```
for (var i = 0; i < e.series.data.length; i++) {
  if (e.series.data[i].valueColor != "" && e.series.data[i].fname != "") {
    color = e.series.data[i].valueColor,
      legendName = e.series.data[i].fname
  }
}
var label = new kendo.drawing.Text(legendName, [0, 0], {
  fill: {
    color: "black"
  }
});
```

With a demo **http://jsfiddle.net/1ost124j/3/**

Comment: Thanks a lot Dhiraj, it works like a charm! Appreciated again.